# Delete Row in Pandas Dataframe if value in Row, Column Matches Anywhere in Another Column

Tags: python, pandas

What I am looking to do is delete a row in a pandas dataframe if a value in that row matches anywhere in another column.  Here is a rough mocked up example in Excel:

[image]

So, in this case, I would like to delete row 2 because that email address was found in Column C.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: `df = df[df.B.isin(df.C)]`

Comment: @QuangHoang I think you missed `~` operator ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with the `~` operator to get the opposite with boolean indexing, you can read it as `not isin`

```
# Print example dataframe
print(df)
   Company        Email Second Email
0  ABC Inc  abc@abc.com             
1  ABC Inc  123@abc.com  abc@abc.com
2  XYZ Inc  jkl@xyz.com
```

Use `isin`

```
df = df[~df['Second Email'].isin(df['Email'])]

print(df)
   Company        Email Second Email
0  ABC Inc  abc@abc.com             
2  XYZ Inc  jkl@xyz.com
```

Comment: This is lovely and perfect!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can create another dataframe using `df[~df.b.isin(de.c)]`

This will look for all b that are not in c (the ~ at the beginning, is like the !)